# SQL Query keeps returning multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this SQL Query to get the remaining benefits for a particular patient, expecting it to return a single row since the patient id is unique, but it keeps returning multiple rows. How do I fix this? DBMS is MySql

```
 select Plan.pBenefitMax - sum(Transaction.employerTotal) as RemainingBenefit
 from Patient
 inner join Plan on Patient.pPlanId = Plan.planId
 inner join Transaction on Patient.patientId = Transaction.tPatientId
  where Patient.patientId = 1
 Group by Plan.pBenefitMax;
```

Comment: You'll get a row for each `pBenefitMax` value, not for each patient, since that's what you say in `GROUP BY`. Try `GROUP BY Patient.patientId`.

Comment: And since you have `WHERE Patient.ptiendId = 1` you don't even need `GROUP BY`.

Comment: your  question is not clear and  " but it keeps returning multiple rows " is in contrast woth the group by you have  .. so  try add  a proper data sample and your expected  result

Comment: Sample input?  Expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this does not get a single row, you either have duplicate PatientId values or the PatientId is linked to more than one Plan.

```
  SELECT Plan.pBenefitMax - 
         (SELECT SUM(`Transaction`.employerTotal) 
            FROM `Transaction` 
           WHERE `Transaction`.tPatientId = Patient.patientId) 
         AS RemainingBenefit
    FROM Patient
    JOIN Plan ON Patient.pPlanId = Plan.planId
   WHERE Patient.patientId = 1;
```